# Angular 6 - Reading JSON response from a POST

Tags: angular

```
  this.http.post('http://localhost:1337/upload', formData, httpOptions)
    .subscribe( res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
```

The code above is working just fine, however, I don't know how to read the response.

This is the response I get:

`[
  {
    "_id": "5b588e82dfba462415d68d67",
    "name": "portal.jpg",
    "hash": "565a716df5de4d968779bffd6b99668a",
    "ext": ".jpg",
    "mime": "image/jpeg",
    "size": "976.35",
    "url": "http://localhost:1337/uploads/565a716df5de4d968779bffd6b99668a.jpg",
    "provider": "local",
    "related": [],
    "createdAt": "2018-07-25T14:51:46.012Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-07-25T14:51:46.024Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "id": "5b588e82dfba462415d68d67"
  }
]`

I specifically need to read `url` and set it to a variable, how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your component `.ts` file have a variable named `uploadUrl` and assign it as,

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:1337/upload', formData, httpOptions)
    .subscribe( res => {
       this.uploadUrl = res[0].url;
    })
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're sending back an array, so probably:

```
.subscribe( (res: any)=> {
   res[0].url
```

Of course this would get the first value of the response, either send no array and just the object or loop through the response if more than one object and retrieve the urls.

Also, you could add a type to your response for intellisense, create a model and then add

```
 .subscribe( (res: TheModelYouCreated)=> {
```

Answer (score 2):

`myurl = res[0]["url"]`

should work. Try `console.log(res[0])` to understand why we need `res[0]`. It uses the same syntax behind

`arr = [0, 1, 2, 3]
console.log(arr[2]) // 2`

Make sure to define `myurl` before `this.http.post`.